# Kohana: why won't this route generate fully?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have the following route in my bootstrap:

```
Route::set('cycleadmin', '(<lang>/)cycleadmin(/<model>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array(
    'lang' => $lang_options,
    'model' => '[a-z_]{0,}',
    'action' => '[a-z_]+',
    'id' => '\d+',
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'cycleadmin',
    'lang' => DEFAULT_LANG,
    'model' => 'cycle',
    'action' => NULL,
));
```

Then I have the following uri request to generate the route:

```
echo Route::get('cycleadmin')->uri(array('action' => 'add'));
```

But this ends up only returning: `/cycleadmin`

I'm using Kohana 3.1 (v3.1.1.1). This worked perfectly in Kohana 3.0.9.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to also set `<model>` . Does it work?

Regards

Sorin

Comment: Yes, then it does, but why do I need to set model? Shouldn't it just use the default?

Comment: In your route `action` is a inner-segment, so it will be ignored when parent (`model`) not set. Default values are used only for route parsing

Comment: Kohana 3.1 no longer uses your "defaults" array when generating the URI. You have explicitly set all parameters that you want included.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.1, the route::get()-method doesn't fill in the defaults - you have to manually specify every parameter. Don't ask me why, but it is intended behaviour (source: the official forums).